# react-app-rewired is not recognized as an internal command (even if I uninstalled it)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, package

Some time ago, I installed the following package:

```
npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
```

I had to change the `package.json` from this:

```
  "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

to this

```
  "scripts": {
   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Then, I uninstalled the package. The package.json was changed back.

But after running `npm start`, I get this error:

```
'react-app-rewired' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

...even if the code was changed.

Does anyone know why this is happening ?

I tried to uninstall it with `--save-dev` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a stale lock file?

Comment: @DanielBank no I don't have one

Answer (score 0):

Try using `yarn` and downgrade your node version with node version manager `nvm`.